# Sorting a List of Lists by the amount of intergers of the same type they contain

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

Hey everyone I have a list of lists which I am trying to sort based on how many of the same type of int it contains. Each item in the list of list contains 4 ints, for ex:

[0,1,2,3]
[0,1,1,1]
[0,2,2,2] etc. Im trying to sort the lists based on which contains the most of a specific int. So if I wanted to sort these three the [0,1,1,1] list would be on top since it contains three 1's etc. I was told to use linq to do this, but didnt know how to use linq.orderby with a method. Can someone help me if there is the correct approach? Thanks!

```
public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<List<int>> listOfPaths = new List<List<int>>();

    public void sortListofLists ()
    {
        listOfPaths.OrderBy(runeList => runeList.customMethod(runeType)); //rune type is an int
    }

    public int customMethod(int sort)
    {
        int holder = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < MethodList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (MethodList[i] == sort)
            {
                holder++;
            }
        }
        return holder;

}
```

Comment: Why isn't `{ 0, 2, 2, 2 }` just as good as `{ 0, 1, 1, 1 }` as they both have 3 of a kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just order descending by count of particular digits:

```
var list = new List<List<int>>() 
{ 
    new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, 
    new List<int> { 0, 1, 1, 1 }, 
    new List<int> { 0, 2, 2, 2 } 
};

var result = list.OrderByDescending(c => c.Count(y => y == 1)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great :) One thing though, what exactly does Count(y => y ==1 ) do?

Comment: `c` is inner list, `y` is element in c. So it counts elements that are equal to `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem can be separated into two sub-problems.

**1. How to get the count of the most frequent integer in List?**

You can use the following LINQ query:

```
int countOfMostOccurences = arr.GroupBy(x => x).Max(x => x.Count());
```

**2. How to sort a List by a certain rule in descending order:**

```
list = list.SortByDescending(x => rule);
```

**Now, combine it:**

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    new List<int> { 1, 3, 3, 3 },
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 3 },
    new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
};

lists = lists.OrderByDescending(x => x.GroupBy(g => g).Max(g => g.Count())).ToList();
```

Comment: Am I missing something? `which contains the most of a SPECIFIC int.`. More: you will be surprised but with this code this `[0,2,2,2]` will apprear  before `[0,1,1,1] ` if it appears in list before: `[0,1,2,3] [0,2,2,2]  [0,1,1,1]`. One more: just ordering list will not order the list - you must assign the result of ordering to something.

Comment: Your solution looks good - but doesn't solve the prolbem. You sorted the list by the max occurance of any value. The question was _...which contains the most of a specific int_. In that case the answer of @GiorgiNakeuri is correct and short.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This solution works good for sorting by the count of occurence of any most frequent integer. The question and its title just wasn't clear. If the OP needs an array to be sorted by the count of specific int, then he should accept the answer of @GiorgiNakeuri.

Comment: Seems that OP's `contains most of a specific int` does not mean `to start with a specific int and with it occur the most in`, cannot even see the code provided include this feature.